# How to handle error in paging3 using Remote mediator with viewPager2

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

I am using [`RemoteMediator`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/v3-network-db) to populate my `Viewpager2`. The view pager contains weekly data and it is in RTL format because i have to show data in descending order. current week, last week.... Please refer below pictures.

[image]

So i am able to fetch data and populate the DB properly. The problem i am facing is in Error Handling.

I went through [LoadState](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging/load-state) documentation and not able to grasp fully. The `LoadstateViewHolder` extends `RecyclerViewHolder`. So will it work with `ViewPager2` ?

The requirement I have is like below :

1. If there is no data available in cloud, create a page and show "-" as data for all the dates for current week only.
   [image]
2. If there is data available in local db and REFRESH is giving any error, PREPEND a page in viewpager with "-" data for current week.

[image]

I can not share the code for official purposes..
Any help will be appreciated..
Thanks.